# Symfony2: form error displaying

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, message

I need to validate field in a Symfony2 form. It's OK, but the error is always displayed next to the related fields.

In case of any error, I also would like to display a message at the form of the form which would say 'Carreful, one or more fields are not valid, please look below'.

Is it possible ? Should I use a custom constraint to add a violation ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your form name is **form**, you can do the following in your view (twig)

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
   Carreful, one or more fields are not valid, please look below
{% endif %}
```